# clean URL & URL rewrite with .htaccess in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-url-manager

how make this url simpler http://localhost/yii-application/frontend/web/site/booking like  http://localhost/controller/action in yii2 ?

`http://localhost/yii-application/frontend/web/site/booking`

i need simpler like :

```
http://localhost/yii-application/controller/action
```

how i can handle this with .htaccess

Comment: why do you want to use a htaccess file? It would be easier to set the DocumentRoot property in the VirtualHost Entry inside the configuration.

Comment: i think the .htaccess config is better cos all routing is correct

Comment: the problem in this case: your public directory (web) is not your DocumentRoot directory and so you can address files deeper in your filesystem than usualy wanted. But I will post you a solution with .htaccess in a few minutes

Comment: please specify which part of the top url is projectname, which is controller and which is the action. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By put this url manger :

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

        ] ]
```

you will achieve this

```
 http://localhost/yii-application/controller/action
```